# Print() is giving me a syntax error. 3.4.1

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so I was making a simple money converter that changes pounds to dollars. However, the last line kept getting syntax errors. It highlights the word 'print' in red. I've tried multiple times but can't get it right. I'm on version 3.4.1. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance. :)

```
print ("Type Convert() to start converting Pounds to US Dollars.")

def Convert():        
   print ("The exchange rate is: £1 to $1.63")        
   pound = int(input ("Enter amount of Pounds you want to convert: £"))        
   (dollar = 1.63 * pound)    
   print ("{0} has been converted. You have {1} dollars.".format(pound, dollar))
```

I edited the code. I think it fixed the old errors but now it has an error on the '=' on the 4th line.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the last line. Count up how many `(` and `)` you have. (This exact case, by the way—passing the result of `format` to another function—accounts for 80% of my syntax errors… So I'd like to say that you'll eventually get to the point where you stop doing this, but more likely at best you'll get to the point where `SyntaxError` makes you start typing `^Iformat` before you even finish reading the message…)

Comment: You're missing closing parentheses...

Comment: Top tip: when you get a `SyntaxError`, *check your syntax*.

Comment: @abarnert and the `pound = ` line :)

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, didn't notice that because my eye immediately went to the `format` line. :)

Comment: The closed bracket didn't help. But thank you anyways.

Comment: By the way, don't post Python code as runnable snippets. Sadly, that doesn't work yet; only JavaScript (or JS/CSS/HTML).

Comment: @Hannah: First, if you have two syntax errors, you have to fix both of them before the `SyntaxError` goes away. Second, don't just say "didn't help", show us your new code and the error. Also, in general, always post the complete traceback, not just "I get a syntax error" or "it doesn't work".

Comment: I added both of the brackets you've mentioned but now the '=' has a error.

Comment: @abarnet Sorry. I'm new to this

Comment: I don't know if this helps but it doesn't show anything in the shell when I try to run it.

Answer (score 2):

There are three mistakes in your code, all involving parentheses.

First, you need to add a `)` to the end of this line:

```
    pound = int(input ("Enter amount of Pounds you want to convert: £")
```

The line currently has two `(` but only one `)`, which is a problem.

Secondly, get rid of the parentheses on this line:

```
    (dollar = 1.63 * pound)
```

Python doesn't allow parentheses around assignment statements, and even if it did, they would be completely unnecessary here.

Last, once again you're missing a `)` at the end of a line:

```
    print ("{0} has been converted. You have {1} dollars.".format(pound, dollar)
```

Comment: It's important to point out that assignment in python is a statement, and not an expression.  That's why putting it in parentheses won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on circular brackets at lot of places.

Try running this.

```
print ("Type Convert() to start converting Pounds to US Dollars.")

def Convert():
    print ("The exchange rate is: £1 to $1.63")
    pound = int(input ("Enter amount of Pounds you want to convert: £"))
    dollar = 1.63 * pound
    print ("{0} has been converted. You have {1} dollars.".format(pound, dollar))

Convert()
```

Comment: It now runs perfectly, thank you!

Comment: And is the Convert() at the end necessary for the code to work?

Comment: `Convert()` is to make call to the function Convert that you define.If you don't call it , it will not run.